# Reactivate a closed user

Tags: docusignapi

We are creating users and closing them through the REST API.  If a user is closed, how do you reactive them through the REST or SOAP api?  I see in the UI you just Send them the activation email again and it re-actives the User.  How would you do this through the API?

Comment: did you manage to find anything? I also inspected the network monitor on the browser and found that on clicking Reactivate against the Closed user, they invoke an API which sends an attribute `sendActivationEmail` with value `send`, but it doesn't seem to help. Obviously, the API exposed to the UI is different from the REST API we're supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you recreate the user with the same exact information, it will reopen the closed user and resend the activation.

See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035194/1219543

Comment: I hoped so too, but it doesn't seem like that. If you send a POST request with the same details, it creates a new user alongside the user that still shows as closed. That's because creating a user (even with same details) results in a new userId

Comment: Yes, I asked that question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get their User ID and call the UpdateUsers API as such:

```
PUT {VX}/accounts/{accountid}/users/

{
    "users": [{
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "sendActivationEmail": "send"
    }]
}
```