# Docusign - API to reactivate a closed user

Tags: docusignapi

I've been able to reactivate a closed Docusign user from the Admin Console, but is there a REST API for that? The Users doc doesn't seem to mention this.

I know there's a [similar question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907375/reactivate-a-closed-user), but there was no resolution found yet. I'm posting this question again hoping that it gets the attention of Docusign people, as they recommend posting API-related questions on SO rather than their own support/community forums.

Also, if there's an API that does exist to recreate/reactivate a deleted user, please document it with clarity. Spelling out what each REST operation does and how it affects something are very important to developers who use such API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reactivate the deleted user by passing the same user details to [CreateUsers](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/create/) api.

Please note that the email/password/userName combination should match the user that was deleted.

Here is a sample request to the [CreateUsers](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/create/) API.

```
{
  "newUsers": [
    {
      "email": "johnsmith@acme.com",
      "password": "**********",
      "userName": "johnsmith"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I was initially passing the userId of the deleted user in the payload assuming it would recreate as is. Also, password doesn't seem to be mandatory. I was able to create and recreate the user without password. What happens if it's left out? Will there be an auto-generated password and sent to the user's email address?

Comment: I tried - it does not reactivate the old user but creates a new one with the same details. So, it's not the same as "reactivating".

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible to do via the UserId and an UpdateUsers call

```
PUT {VX}/accounts/{accountid}/users/

{
    "users": [{
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "sendActivationEmail": "send"
    }]
}
```