# How to reactivate a closed user using REST api - Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

This question was already asked in stack overflow but still i didn't get the solution.

[Docusign - API to reactivate a closed user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996821/docusign-api-to-reactivate-a-closed-user)

1) I tried to create the duplicate user as same like closed user, but user gets created with new userId.

2) I tried to update the userStatus value from "Closed" to "ActivationSent" and "Active". It returns with status-200 but userStatus attribute value is not updated

I didn't found any documentation, Please assist me

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the user's userId and then make below API call:

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/users
```

Body:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "userId": "<userId>",
        "sendActivationEmail": "send"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please accept this as answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: @MohamedHaneef: Please accept answers once it resolves your qs, this will help other SO memebers in getting their queries resolved quickly.

Comment: The suggested answer works and I am new to this community so please assist me on to accept the answer. Thanks once again